# Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout Android XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to set Admob Banner on bottom of ExtendedViewPager but I am not success to do it. I am getting error that `Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout`
I want My Smart Banner Ads at Bottom of the XML.

My XML is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.karopass.karoshare.ImageDetails">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_imageDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.example.utils.ExtendedViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_extended"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_imageDetails"
        android:background="@color/image_back"/>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/floating_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu_colorNormal="@color/fab_menu"
        app:menu_labels_colorNormal="@color/btn_fab_labels_color"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ll_adLayout_image"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/button_likeDislike"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/fab_button"
            android:src="@mipmap/fav"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="Like (10)" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/button_share_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/fab_button"
            android:src="@mipmap/share_white"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="Share" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/button_copy_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/fab_button"
            android:src="@mipmap/copy"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="" />


    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/ll_adLayout_image"
        android:layout_below="@+id/floating_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone please check and help me to solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused because there is a circular reference in the layout parameters.

you are giving `LinearLayout` property `android:layout_below="@+id/floating_menu"` and in `FloatingActionButton` you are giving `android:layout_above="@+id/ll_adLayout_image"` that' why the Exception is occurs.

Comment: Thanks Bro....its working fine....You have saved my day...I will accept answer in 5 minute. Thanks a lot

Comment: @AvantikaSharma glad to know that.

Answer (score 0):

Here you define your LinearLayout - `ll_adLayout_image` below of `floating_menu`  and then also defining your `floating_menu` above of `ll_adLayout_image` Linear layout this is the circular dependency, 
For the resolve problem you need to remove any one dependency,

Code with resolved problem :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.karopass.karoshare.ImageDetails">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_imageDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.example.utils.ExtendedViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_extended"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_imageDetails"
        android:background="@color/image_back"/>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/floating_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu_colorNormal="@color/fab_menu"
        app:menu_labels_colorNormal="@color/btn_fab_labels_color"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ll_adLayout_image"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/button_likeDislike"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/fab_button"
            android:src="@mipmap/fav"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="Like (10)" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/button_share_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/fab_button"
            android:src="@mipmap/share_white"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="Share" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/button_copy_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/fab_button"
            android:src="@mipmap/copy"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="" />


    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/ll_adLayout_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```